# Tuckey URLRewriteFilter and Spring MVC - no mapping found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm using URLRewriteFilter to rewrite some urls in my Spring MVC application.

But I have problem with request mapping.
What I want to do is whenever user enter request /sessiontimeout the url will be rewritten to /timeout.html.

So I configure the application to use URLRewriteFilter and add a rule as following:

```
<urlrewrite>    
    <rule>
        <from>/sessiontimeout</from>
        <to type="redirect" >%{context-path}/timeout.html</to>
    </rule>     
</urlrewrite>
```

The problem is when I enter /sessiontimeout, the system redirect to /timeout.html. But I got no mapping found exception, because there is no mapping for /timeout.html in the controller (I used annotation for request mapping).

Do I need to add request mapping for /timeout.html to my controller?
It seems doesn't make sense.